# I hope this clarifies your question

Tags: word-usage

On the web, I see many examples of answers given by professional support that end like this:

> <*Answer to the asker's question*>
>
> I hope this clarifies your question.

I am surprised by this closing sentence. The question itself often was perfectly clear.
Is this usage correct?
Comparing with a sentence like "*Could you please clarify your question?*" I feel like there is a discrepancy.

Comment: You're right. It should be, "I hope this answers your question", or similar. Perhaps the responders are experts in their area but not native English speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify means to make something clearer. Clarifying a question would mean making the question clearer so it could be understood. It would not be possible to answer an unclear question! If a question is unclear, only the asker can really clarify it.

However, let's say you had a question about a certain matter that was causing you confusion - the subject of your question. A person answering the question may have clarified the subject matter for you. So, it is quite common to hear answers to questions end with statements such as "*I hope that clarifies the matter for you*".